# 'tuple' object is not callable?

Tags: python-3.7

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-08821007cb29> in <module>
      1 values= input(' Enter some comma separated numbers : ')  # Your help here will be much appreciated
      2 List= values.split(',')
----> 3 x= tuple(List)
      4 print('List : ', List)
      5 print('Tuple : ', x)

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

The above is my entire code, and i can't figure out where is the error. Also I am using a jupyter note from anaconda and my python version is 3.7.4.

Comment: You created a variable called `tuple` somewhere above and shadowed the built-in. Don't create variables with the same name as built-ins like you're trying to do with `tuple = tuple(List)`.

Comment: Don't name variables after built-in function names or else these errors can happen.

Comment: Tried to rename it but it produces the same error

Comment: @AmrSaber You can't "un-overwrite" something after the fact without some trickery. Clear the console you're working in and/or reload whatever environment you're working in.

Comment: @AmrSaber `print(tuple)` just before that line. It will print a tuple and thats why you can't do `tuple()`.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, it worked :)